# composition of a vector filed with a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $X$ be a vector field,  $M$ be a smooth surface and  $v \in T_p M $ and a curve $γ :I \rightarrow M$ s.t. $γ(0)=p, γ'(0)=v$

then we can define the "derivative" of $X$ as $\frac{d}{dt}(X\circ γ)|_{t=0 }$

I don't understand this definition, what we mean by $(X\circ γ)$ ?

For instance, take $M=S^2, $ $X(t)=(-\text{sin}t,\text{cos}t,0)$ and $γ(t)=(\text{cos}t,\text{sin}t,0)$ what $(X\circ γ)$ means ?

Comment: In you example, $X(t)$ is not a vector field on the sphere. A vector field is a smooth function $X \colon M \to TM$ such that for all $p\in M$, $X(p) \in T_pM$. Therefore, if $\gamma$ is a path, you get a function $t \in I \mapsto X(\gamma(t)) \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$.

Comment: @Didier can you provide an example, this example I wrote is from my lecture notes I must have copied something wrong from the board or my professor made a mistake.

Comment: What you wrote is a vector field *along a path*, more precisely along the equator. It is not defined on the whole sphere. Take the constant $0$ vector field on the sphere $p\in S^2 \mapsto X(p) = 0 \in T_pS^2$. This is a vector field. Or the vector field on the circle $V \colon e^{i\theta} \in S^1 \mapsto V(e^{i\theta} = i e^{i\theta} \in T_{e^{i\theta}}S^1$. They are examples